# Create hyperlink with concat in XSLT --> HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, hyperlink

Hi and happy year to everyone !

Once again, I need your help with a transformation in XSLT.

I have an XML-TEI file with a lot of pb elements. For instance :

```
<pb ed="bnf" id="f77.image.r"/>
```

I have also in the same file one link element :

```
<link id="bnf" target="http://test.com:/12148/btv1b90621925/"/>
```

My transformation in xslt should not only transform the `<pb>` element to look like this in HTML : [77r] but the [77r] should also be a hyperlink.

Now, it only does the first stuff :

```
<xsl:template match="pb[@ed='bnf']"><span class="pb">
        <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(@id, '.image.'), 'f')"/><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@id, '.image.')">
        </xsl:value-of>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
    </span>
    </xsl:template>
```

How can I reach the link element and do so the [f77r] takes the value of the link and concat it with the id of the pb element ? Every pb should be a hyperlink like this (with the end changing for each pb) :

http://test.com:/12148/btv1b90621925/**f77.image.r**

Thank you so much for your help :)

Best wishes,
Micha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could use a key here, to look up the `link` elements by there `id` attribute.

```
<xsl:key name="links" match="link" use="@id" />
```

Then you can use the key to get the target of the link when you construct the href for the hyperlink

```
<a href="{key('links', @ed)/@target}{@id}">
```

Note the double-use of Attribute Value Templates to create the attribute. You could also write this if you wanted

```
<a href="{concat(key('links', @ed)/@target, @id)}">
```

Try this XSLT template

```
<xsl:template match="pb[@ed='bnf']">
    <span class="pb">
        <a href="{concat(key('links', @ed)/@target, @id)}">
            <xsl:text> [</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(@id, '.image.'), 'f')"/><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(@id, '.image.')">
            </xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:text>] </xsl:text>
        </a>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

This should output the following:

```
<span class="pb">
    <a href="http://test.com:/12148/btv1b90621925/f77.image.r"> [77r] </a>
</span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim C ! It works perfectly well :)